# How can I simplify my Jquery code while keeping addClass and removeClass?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

Every time I add a new `<li>` and `<img>` element I also have to add a new line of code in the .js file

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexK90/pen/xxawYaa) Here is the online code of how it works and how it should continue to work after editing the script.

```js
//Mouseenter
  $(".list li:nth-child(1)").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").removeClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(1)").addClass("show");
  })

  $(".list li:nth-child(2)").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").removeClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(2)").addClass("show");
  })

  $(".list li:nth-child(3)").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").removeClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(3)").addClass("show");
  })

//Mouseleave
  $(".list li:nth-child(1)").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").addClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(1)").removeClass("show");
  })

  $(".list li:nth-child(2)").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").addClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(2)").removeClass("show");
  })

  $(".list li:nth-child(3)").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".img-display img.show").addClass("show");
    $(".img-display img:nth-child(3)").removeClass("show");
  })
```

I wanted to be able to simplify my code by keeping `addClass`, `removeClass`, `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` and not having to add another line of code every time I add new elements.

At the moment I only have this to identify the elements of the list:

```js
  $(".list li").on('mouseenter', function() {
    var index = $(this).index()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you just need a little reasoning for this problem. Here's all you need:

```js
  const lis = $(".list li")
  lis.on('mouseenter', function() {
    const index = lis.index(this)
    
    $(".img-display img.show").removeClass("show");
    $(".img-display img").eq(index).addClass("show")
  })
```